# How to decrease error in (FTCS) forward time centered space method?

Tags: finite-element, pde, finite-difference, differential-equations

I am using the FTCS method for solving differential equations. I know that the condition for stable output is
$$ 
\frac{\alpha \Delta t}{\Delta x ^2} < \frac{1}{2}
$$
But when I use the distance step according to this formula, the size of the step is big and the answer I get is wrong.
Is there some way I can use smaller distance steps in FTCS?

Comment: I suppose that you are solving the heat equation in 1D, is that right?

Comment: The condition only says that the time step can't be too large, but is there a corresponding condition that you can't choose it very small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are some who would say that this is the price you pay for not having to invert a matrix. You traded relatively cheap timestep updates for accuracy. You could switch to an implicit method and take as fine a grid as you like at the cost of having to solve a linear system at each timestep.